# Problems installing pcloud on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, pcloud

Recently I obtained a Raspberry Pi 400 and I have tried to install pcloud Drive on the Ubuntu that I have installed with the Raspberry Pi Imager on a MicroSD with 128Gb.

I have tried the indicated steps in this official website: [how to install pcloud drive linux](https://www.pcloud.com/how-to-install-pcloud-drive-linux.html)

I downloaded the indicated file there.Then  I open the terminal and execute the next commands for to install:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ chmod +x pcloud
```

These commands return nothing

Now, the downloaded file should be executable, but when I try to run it (double click or right click and then selecting 'Run') nothing happens.
Also I have tried to run the file from another folder, but nothing still happens.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I hope that the edits I have made are close to what you have indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pcloud` in a shell:

```
cd ~/Downloads
./pcloud
```

The shell shows a log of what `pcloud` is doing.
Also, in Ubuntu's System Monitor widget you should see one `pcloud` process using CPU. On that process, right-click to look at the open flies. That also gives an idea what `pcloud` is doing

Answer (score 0):

Before you run the pcloud file, run these commands in your terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install libfuse2
```

Solution from here:
https://www.pcloud.com/how-to-install-pcloud-drive-linux.html